# How can I control a javascript Map keys order?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, data-structures, hashmap

I'm using a [javascript Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in my project as a data set and I thought that when I set a value to an already existing key his position in the object won't change. Turns out that whenever I use the `set()` function it deletes the the pair and inserts it in the end of the map.
Is there any way I can control the the items position in the map so that whenever I update an existing value it won't be moved to the end?

Comment: No, you cannot. The order of the keys when you iterate through them is strictly the insertion order. The most recently inserted or updated keys are at the end.

Comment: Use an array of keys if you want to control the order, reorder elements, or sort them.